# how to use gif image as splash screen and how to start and stop gif in nativescript-Angular app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to use gif image as splash screen for nativescript-Angular App. I don't know whether we can use Gif image as splash Screen. if there is any option to work that GIF format image then how to use and start gif and stop gif in App for both the platform I am using nativescript 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nativescript-splashscreen](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-splashscreen) for animated `Splash Screens`. That plugin is available at Nativescript marketplace and you can add using the following command

`tns plugin add nativescript-splashscreen`

Comment: gif image format I can not use in this plugin it taking png format image and animating that image

Comment: You can not use a GIF (at least on iOS) for splash screen, but idea is to add an animated view as soon the app starts. You may customize the animated splash screen view from the plugin, adjust as per your needs.